# Minimum size of a window

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm developing an UWP app and I would like to set a minimum window size (in desktop)

I've been looking and I do not know where this is done.

Answer (score 6):

You can set some of 'Windows' properties in *ApplicationView* class. There is a method that allows to set the Minimum size of application window (desktop only) - [*SetPreferredMinSize*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_SetPreferredMinSize_Windows_Foundation_Size_). However, this accepts values only from certain range:

> The smallest allowed minimum size is 192 x 48 effective pixels. The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the allowed bounds.

To do what you want you will have to set it upon app launching:

```cs
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(300, 300));
```

Note that you also can set a preferred launch size with other property:

```cs
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(600, 600);
```

Comment: One key thing to note Is that you are providing DIPS, not PIXELS, for this API. See [this code](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_uwp/Main.cpp) for an example of usage.

Comment: @FernandoSousa You should put this in app.xaml.cs before activating the window.

Comment: It gives an error. This is my app.xaml.cs:
`sealed partial class App : BootStrapper
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SplashFactory = (e) => new Views.Splash(e);
        }

        public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            // TODO: add your long-running task here
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(Views.MainPage));
        }
    }`

Comment: @FernandoSousa You have provided too little code and no exception message and information. Besides, I don't see how this is connected to my answer and comments shouldn't be used to ask new questions.

Comment: This is my code, I do not know where to put this code: `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(300, 300));`

Comment: @FernandoSousa I'm not sure what template are you using, give it a try - for example before navigating. Generally you can put it anywhere, ensuring only that applicationview is ready. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) you can use minWidth and minHeight properties in the xaml.

Comment: This is for the page control not the window size